# Different argparse rules if only one argument is given

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, argparse

I am using `nargs='+'` in an argparse argument, and required different processing if there is only one argument than if there is multiple. I am using `.csv` files as input; if there is only one, I can use that as input for the rest of the code, however if there is multiple I first need to merge them into one `.csv`

My current code is:

```
parser.add_argument('-csv', nargs='+', help=".csv file(s)")
```

And I need to be able to say

```
if only one .csv file:
    then
else (if multiple .csv files):
    merge the .csvs
```

Comment: Just to clear things up, I don't need the ````then```` or ````merge the .csvs```` given in the answer, they are just placeholders. Thanks

Comment: You're gathering the arguments into a list right?  Can't you just check the length of the list?

Comment: When you say merge - do you mean treat all the files as a continuous stream? Do the CSV files all have headers/not for instance? Seems like depending on what you're wanting to do, then you can just loop over the csv filenames in turn and do whatever you need.

Comment: `Special cases aren't special enough` - how exactly does your merging algorithm work, that it can handle two or more inputs, but not one?

Comment: In answer to Jon, I hadn't considered using a continuous stream so will have to look into if I'm able to do that. In answer to Karl, the merging algorithm  required having at least two inputs as for the first file it saves the header and for the ensuing it uses ````__next__()```` to skip the header

Comment: @Jonathan are the csv files guaranteed to be consistent in headers - eg: *only* the first file has important information - the logic is just only really to not consider the header? Are you using `csv.DictReader` or `csv.reader`?

Comment: Neither, I am using Pandas, and the csvs are guaranteed to be consistent - so the headers of each file are the same

Comment: @Jonathan oh well - pandas has a different solution - that's actually quite an important detail for the question... and it can already handle differing headers if you wanted that...

Comment: @Jonathan for instance... what about `df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(filename) for filename in args.csv])`? Might want to reset reset of the index if you want a range index again and not the position in the files themselves...

Comment: (or something like `df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(filename) for filename in args.csv], keys=args.csv)` if you want a multi-index etc...)

Comment: If it affects things, my code doesn't required sorting, as I haven't written it yet, but I had planned it as if it will (using ````shift````)

Comment: Okay... well... seems you've accepted an answer that wasn't by the looks of it what you were really asking anyway (involving pandas) - so... _shrugs_... not sure what help can be given here without further clarification etc...

Comment: Many apologies Jon, I appreciate your help with this, it's just that in direct terms of the question this wasn't necessarily about the csvs, I just used that because I will be using csvs, the question itself doesn't change depending on the input. The information about how to read in multiple files is very useful and will definitely make me revise/rethink my code but I felt I ought to accept the answer given as it does answer the question which I asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nargs='+'` returns a list, you can check if the length of the list is equal to 1. I can see from the example that you want to check if you got **only one** `csv` file.

```
parser.add_argument('-csv', nargs='+', help=".csv file(s)")
args = parser.parse_args()
if len(args.csv) == 1:
   # one files
else:
   # many files
```